# Redacted crashes on iOS 13.4 beta?

Tags: xcode, crashlytics, ios13

I have started seeing a high number of crashes in Crashlytics that I can't diagnose. Seems to be a memory issue because the crashes comes up as:

```
Crashed: com.apple.root.default-qos
EXC_BREAKPOINT
```

However, the trace is entirely redacted:

```
0 libxpc.dylib <redacted> + 88
1 (Missing)
2 (Missing)
3 (Missing)
4 (Missing)
5 (Missing)
6 (Missing)
7 (Missing)
8 libdispatch.dylib <redacted> + 32
9 (Missing)
10 (Missing)
11 (Missing)
12 (Missing)
13 (Missing)
14 (Missing)
```

The only silver lining is the issue is limited exclusively to iOS 13.4, so hopefully it's just a beta bug. But I have no idea how to proceed. Help!

Comment: might be helpful to include the device types that this crash happened on. And are you able to see if the application was in the background when it happened?

Comment: Mike, are you still running into this with crashes coming from iOS 13.4 beta?

Comment: I have similar crashes. Have you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, there's nothing you can do about this yourself. Crashlytics needs to add support for symbolication of these crashes for iOS 13.4. Usually, this is done pretty fast. Guess they're a bit slower this cycle. I hope they resolve this before 13.4 is officially released.